# Multiply time series dataframe by series?

Tags: python, pandas

This seems like it should be simple, but I can't figure out how to multiply each column of a pandas dataframe by its respective value in a series:

```
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')
ts1 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
ts2 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
df=pd.DataFrame({"ts1":ts1, "ts2":ts2})
s3=pd.Series([3,4])
df.mul(s3, axis=0)  # Gives 2 columns of NaNs
df.mul(s3, axis=1)  # Gives 4 columns of NaNs
```

The goal here is just to have all the values of ts1 in the dataframe multiplied by 3 and all the values of ts2 in the dataframe multiplied by 4. `mul` seems to work fine if df is composed of non-time-series `Series`.

Comment: Though I'm using Pandas alot now, anyone who says it's ready to replace Matlab for timeseries work just has to try to do this.  ARRRGGGG.

Answer (score 0):

To multiply two Series, they need to have the same index (length and value). You can do the multiplication, like so,

```
s3 = pd.Series([3]*len(df.index), index = df.index)
s4 = pd.Series([4]*len(df.index), index = df.index)
df1 = df.ts1 * s3
df2 = df.ts2 * s4
```

Comment: So I have to multiply each series in the dataframe individually and then re-combine them into a new dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

After a few more hours of messing with it, I got this to work:

```
df.apply(lambda row: list(r * m for r, m in zip(row, s3)), axis=1)
```